# How to use date time format

Tags: java

I am using date time format, to print date time in a specific pattern, but my compiler is throwing an error.

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.time.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class fewdays{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
        LocalDate then = today.minusDays( 2 ) ;
        LocalTime time_ago = LocalTime.now();

        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(then, time_ago);

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dtf.format(dt));

    }
}
```

Now the compiler shows this error message :

```
 error: cannot find symbol
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                                    ^
 symbol:   variable DateTimeFormatter
 location: class fewdays
```

Comment: You just need to import the class -> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Comment: `dtf.format(dt)` should basically be `dt.format(dtf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `DateTimeFormatter` class so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeFornatter` is in package `java.time.format`.

So you have to add

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Read your question and find out that it is the common import package error.
So What you need to do here is Import **java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter** package to your program and See It will work.

I've already Correct your program and pasted below.

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class fewdays{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
        LocalDate then = today.minusDays( 2 ) ;
        LocalTime time_ago = LocalTime.now();

        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(then, time_ago);

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dtf.format(dt));

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not add code with description *Try this*. Write what you have done and why.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the specification of what I've done and why it is needed.
Thanks, Jens.